# A similar method like presence but considers false to be present

Tags: ruby, activesupport

Just realized that calling `.presence` on a `false` boolean returns `nil` instead of `false`. Is there anything similar that basically considers `false` to be present?

For example:

```
irb(main):012:0> data = true
=> true
irb(main):013:0> data.presence
=> true
irb(main):014:0> data = false
=> false
irb(main):015:0> data.presence
=> nil
```

In my case, I have some database attributes that are set to `false`, but they are actually valid values, so returning `nil` can be a little confusing.

For example:

```
irb(main):016:0> fallback = "hello world"
=> "hello world"
irb(main):017:0> data.presence || fallback
=> "hello world"
```

Just would be nice if there's something like this:

```
irb(main):014:0> data = false
=> false
irb(main):016:0> fallback = "hello world"
=> "hello world"
irb(main):017:0> data.presence || fallback
=> false
```

I have a lot of conditions in one of my models that uses a "fallback" technique and I realized that this is being called a lot because the user has selected `false` in many of these scenarios.

Comment: Check for equality: `data == false` would be true.

Comment: If the user actually selected `false`, then `data == false` would return `true` instead of `false` like the user selected. I think this would basically create the reverse effect where `nil` now returns `false` and `false` returns `true` based on that condition.

Comment: Just use `.nil?`

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
data.nil? ? fallback : data
```